# Lambda Expression Entity Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity collection tied to another entity (navigation property) I will always have one but for some reason it brings it back as a collection. I need to be able to change one property on this object, the DateViewed property.

var test = _personDetail.CurrentPerson.RecentlyViewed;

is there a way to use this new test object in a lambda expression to change the DateViewed property to DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note, I am not 100% certain what you are asking - ie which part comes back as collection, and what `RecentlyViewed` is (did you mean `DateViewed` as you mention elsewhere? Taking a guess here - let me know if this isn't what you meant.*

If you know there will always be one and only one item in the `CurrentPerson` collection, you can use `Single()` - ie:

```
_personDetail.CurrentPerson.Single().DateViewed = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thanks..sorry for the delay, this worked perfectly for what i needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

If it is coming back as a collection and it should not be, you need to go into the designer and set the relationship correctly.

---

Click on the relationship (the line adjoining the two entities) in the designer, open the properties window, and make sure the `End --> Multiplicity` property is set to `1 (One)` for that end of the relationship.

If it is a *"Many-to-one"* relationship *(ie. the other end of the relationship is set to `* (Many)`)*, you'll also want to open the Mapping Details *(View --> Other Windows --> Mapping Details)* and make sure *Association --> Maps to...* is set to the **Many* side of the relationship.

Once this is complete, you should be able to set the `DateViewed` property like this:

```
_personDetail.CurrentPerson.DateViewed = DateTime.Now;
```